# Math.random with changing values

Tags: java

I have this dilemma with a script

I want to do a *Bingo* game and here I'd use this `Math.random` script

```
public class Bingo{
    public static void main(String[]args){ 

        int num = (int) (Math.random() *(75)) +1;

        int x = 0;

        while(x==0){

            System.out.println(num +"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

In this case my output is always **34**

Is there a way so that my output is always a different number? Thanks!

Comment: Add `num = (int) (Math.random() *(75)) +1;` to your loop ?

Comment: But in that case numbers could be repeated right?

Comment: Sure, but at least you won't always get the same.You may try another approach e.g populating a list with all possible numbers, then randomly picking numbers from the list, and remove them from the list  (which will only contain remaining un-chosen numbers).

Comment: I don't know if creating an infinite loop is a good idea. Maybe you should change the value of `x`somewhere.

Comment: @C.Champagne is there a way to stop the loop after the 75th time it runs please?

Comment: `while(x<75){ x++; ...` or use a `for` loop :  `for(int x =0; x <75; x++){ ...`

Comment: @Benit see my previous comment and donot hesitate to take time to learn the language and be comfortable with the basics.

Comment: @C.Champagne Thank you for your time... I found the answer. And yeah I guess I need a lot more time to learn all the basics.

Answer (score 3):

First using `Math.random()` gives a *floating* point value. It is **not advisable** to use that for random integer generation. So I'll use `random.nextInt()` here.

Secondly you'll need a `set` to maintain previously generated numbers and `break` the loop when `size` of the `set` hits `75`. You can `continue` the loop if you've already generated that number.

**Here's the code.**

```
    int num = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    while (set.size() < 75) {
        num = r.nextInt(75) + 1;
        if (set.contains(num))
            continue;
        set.add(num);
        System.out.println(num + "\n");
    }
```

imports:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
```

Comment: That's step 1    Step 2 is that the random number doesn't get duplicated when outputted

Comment: I'm a beginner and this could be a dumb question but for Random, Set and HashSet it outputs cannot find symbol... also I am using BlueJ as my IDE could that be the case?

Comment: add the imports as well.

Comment: Thank you so much very helpful!

Comment: @ShanuGupta The problem with this approach is that once you have 74 numbers, you have a 98% chance of generating a number you've already picked. I tested it a couple of times and it took as many as 650 iterations to generate all 75 numbers.

Comment: @Michael agreed!! For bigger numbers yours approach is what I'd take. Clearly op doesn't care much about performance here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement to only draw each number once, you will have to choose a different approach. I would add all balls to a list and then [shuffle the list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)). Then you can iterate over the balls (and perhaps `break` when the game is won) :

```
final List<Integer> balls = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 75; i++) {
    balls.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(balls);

for (int ball : balls) {
    System.out.println(ball); //or whatever your logic is
}
```

Imports:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

Comment: For List, ArrayList and Collections it outputs cannot find symbol... could it be because I am using BlueJ as my IDE?

Comment: @Benit You just need to import the right stuff. I've added the imports you'll need to my answer. Add those lines at the top of your file, after the `package` declaration (if there is one).

Comment: Thank you so much... sorry for the question but I'm a beginner in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your `num` it is always with the same value because you are not changing it inside while loop.

Try something like:

```
/* your code here */
while (x==0) {
    num = (int) (Math.random() *(75)) +1;
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
public class Bingo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        while (x == 0) {

            int num = (int) (Math.random() * (75)) + 1;

            System.out.println(num + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the following code:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min;
```

Where max will be 75 and min is 0. Also both the numbers are inclusive. Please note that the internal algorithm fo math random uses Leniar congruential generator(though not the best), but considering you will be using a 64 bit machine, the numbers should not repeat soon enough.